# Problem with c++ unicode utf-8 decode characters

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to print some encoding characters using "en_US.UTF-8" standard on a Linux machine, but there are some characters that do not appear.
I can see characters from 161 to 255 correctly, but from 128 to 160 I can not see anything. This is the code I am using:

```
int main(void)
{      

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    wchar_t c;

    for (c = 128; c < 256; c++) {
      std::wcout<< " \n" << c << '\n';
       }

    return 0;
}
```

someone who can help me with this? I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Your console might also be limited.

Comment: `wstring` and `wcout` is not for utf8, but utf16 or utf32

Comment: If you're on Linux you might as well use `char` and `std::cout`. I find that `wchar_t` is just a Windows peculiarity really...

Comment: @DeiDei That would produce very different results. It would just write bytes, which the console would try to decode as utf8. Using wchar_t causes them to be treated as unicode codepoints that, with the utf8 locale, get expanded into multibyte sequences right before output.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot It is for utf8 when the output locale is utf8.

Comment: `std::wcout` does not accept `char` data, you would need to change `std::wcout << " \n" << c << '\n';` to `std::wcout << L" \n" << c << L'\n';` instead

Answer (score 5):

The Unicode code points between 128 and 160 represent (non-printable) control codes.

Cf. [Unicode chart table](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf)

Comment: Indeed. While 160 is not a control code, it is nonetheless invisible.